# Command line arg to MSTest

Tags: selenium, mstest

Let me explain what I am trying to achieve.

I have a series of MSTest unit tests, (VS 2010),   that use Selenium to do automated browser testing.  Selenium allows me to set up a grid of computers that have different browsers and versions register themselves.  I can then execute my tests on any registered browser / version pairing.

All of my Test classes inherit from a base class where I set up a Local and Browser,version pair for my tests

In the MyTestInitialize method in the base class I have the following

> // set a locale
>
> //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-CA");
>      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en");
>
> //set up the Selenium Driver
>
> ```
> DesiredCapabilities InternetExplorerBrowser = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();
> InternetExplorerBrowser.SetCapability("browserName", "internet explorer");
> InternetExplorerBrowser.SetCapability("version", "11");
> driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://192.168.0.1:4444/wd/hub"), InternetExplorerBrowser);
> ```

```
/*Uncomment the following lines to use Chrome*/
//DesiredCapabilities ChromeBrowser = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
//ChromeBrowser.SetCapability("browserName", "chrome");
//driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://192.168.0.1:4444/wd/hub"), ChromeBrowser);
```

and so on for Firefox and Safari

I can run all my tests form the VS command line tool but if I want to specify a different browser / version pairing, I need to edit the code above, re-compile then execute to get my desired result.

What I want to do is to be able to execute for different browser / version pairings without having to re-compile.  My first thought was to try passing in a command line arg to MSTest then access those args from within my class and use them to set up my desired browser / version.

I have done some searching on the web and it seems passing custom commandline args into MSTest is not supported.

Any ideas on how I can achieve my goal.

Any thoughts are appreciated.
Sean

Answer (score 0):

I would use traits to solve this. Just add the different browsers as TestCategory in your test and then use the

```
/category:[filter]
```

option when running your test. You would the up with different bat files for executing for example IE, FF and Chrome tests.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I can certainly specify them as a category using something like [TestCategory("IE11"), TestCategory("IE10"), TestCategory("IE9"), TestCategory("Chrome") etc then run from commandline using MSTest.  I still need to set up the correct Selenium Driver in my base class's TestInitialize() method prior to execution and I am not clear on how I can do that.  Sorry, C# is not my strength.